# How to solve SQL Server connection using flask error(windows auth not supported)

Tags: python, sql-server

I get this error when trying to connect to SQL Server hosted on Azure:

> pypyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server.')

This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template
import pypyodbc

app = Flask(__name__)

connection = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};'                         
'Server=tcp:abc,1433;Initial 
'Catalog=LMSDatabase;'
'Persist Security Info=False;'
'User ID=xyz;Password=xyz;'
'MultipleActiveResultSets=False;'                      
'Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;')
 cursor = connection.cursor()
 cursor.execute("Select * from DATE_SHEET")

 for r in cursor.fetchall():
    print(r)
```

Udi and password are hidden

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True
```

To your connection string 
You can specify the connection string as one long string that uses semi-colons (;) as the argument separator.

Working example:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQLServer};Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=myDB;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("Select * from DATE_SHEET")

 for r in cursor.fetchall():
    print(r)
 cnxn.close()
```

Comment: It's still not working.....Stil showing That Windows Login is not supported...this same connection string worked fine in my asp.net web api project but no working in this flask project